# Show algebraically that $\tan x = \frac{\sin2x - \sin x }{\cos2x - \cos x + 1}$

Tags: trigonometry

How can I show this *algebraically*,

> $$\tan x = \frac{\sin2x - \sin x }{\cos2x - \cos x + 1}$$

I don't know where to begin. I simply know, that $\tan x = \dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x}$.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) [Please use MathJax.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)  For some basic information about writing math at this site, see [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189). Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for writing a good question.

Comment: You can begin with clarifying this expression (brackets etc.). And don't forget the $x$ in sin/cos.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html

Comment: I am a new contributor. Not, sure why I get these strange messages. I don't know how to format the content.

Comment: Come on, surely you see that we cannot know where you divide. How can you expect help if you don't clarify?

Comment: Do you mean $\tan x = \dfrac{\sin2x - \sin x }{\cos2x - \cos x + 1}$?

Comment: @Blue, yes! That's what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sin 2x = 2\sin x \cos x$
$\cos 2x = 2\cos^2x-1$

$\dfrac{\sin2x - \sin x }{\cos2x - \cos x + 1} = \dfrac{2\sin x\cos x - \sin x }{2\cos^2x - \cos x } =\dfrac{\sin x(2\cos x-1)  }{\cos x ( 2\cos x - 1)} = \tan x$

Comment: Thx. Damn me, I missed this, I had it on a page of formulas, the rules and the equal of cos2x and sin2x. Damn me.